# Raw File Recovery

Tags: data-recovery, files

Does anybody know of a Linux Ubuntu program that will recover RAW Photo Files that have been deleted in error from a camera card ?

Answer (score 3):

Photorec, it is a part of the testdisk package which is in the ubuntu repositories.

See : [PhotoRec Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

Other options are outlined in [Ubuntu Wiki Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)